# Is it possible to create Stream implementation that counts their elements in a single operation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Q: Is it possible to create Stream implementation that counts their elements in a single operation rather than counting each and every element in the stream?

I came to this though when i tried to compare two methods on a list :

- `size()`
- `count()`

`Stream::count` terminal operation counts the number of elements in a Stream. The complexity of the operation is often **O(N)**, meaning that the number of sub-operations is proportional to the number of elements in the *Stream*.

`List::size` method has a complexity of **O(1)**, which means that regardless of the number of elements in the List, the `size()` method will return in constant time.

```
   List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(0, 100).boxed().collect(toList());
    System.out.println(list.size());
    System.out.println(list.stream().count());
```

---

`size()` took a relative less time than `count()`,so is there any possible way to create Stream implementation that counts their elements in a single operation and make a complexity of **O(1)** ??

---

**Edit** [Article to answer Yes](https://dzone.com/articles/java-stream-is-a-count-always-a-count):

> It is possible to create `Stream` implementation that counts their
>   elements in a single operation **O(1)** rather than counting each and
>   every element in the stream. This can improve performance
>   significantly, especially for streams with many elements.

Comment: @CommonMan To highlight that the default implementation of the `count` is but a special case of reduction and it internally does `return mapToLong(e -> 1L).sum();`, hence the `O(n)` complexity there. In my opinion, `stream`s were not supposedly required to be aware of the size of the underlying data structure backing it and hence iterating through them makes more sense. To quote from [the javadoc of `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) *Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities, have different goals...*

Comment: @Ruslan IMHO, the question doesn't seem to be about what the article already reads but validating if the ways suggested could possibly be practiced. (and should they be or not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is already happening in Java 9 and newer (considering the OpenJDK implementation which is also the base for Oracle’s JDK).

If you want a similar operation, you can use, e.g.

```
public static long count(BaseStream<?,?> s) {
    Spliterator<?> sp = s.spliterator();
    long c = sp.getExactSizeIfKnown();
    if(c >= 0) return c;
    final class Counter implements Consumer<Object>,
        IntConsumer, LongConsumer, DoubleConsumer { // avoid boxing where possible
        long count;
        public void accept(Object t) { count++; }
        public void accept(int value) { count++; }
        public void accept(long value) { count++; }
        public void accept(double value) { count++; }
    }
    Counter c = new Counter();
    sp.forEachRemaining(c);
    return c.count;
}
```

You can check that it won’t process all elements with

```
System.out.println(count(IntStream.range(0, 100).peek(System.out::println)));
System.out.println(count(Stream.of("a", "b", "c").peek(System.out::println)));
```

whereas inserting a `filter` operation like

```
System.out.println(count(Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
    .peek(System.out::println).filter(x -> true)));
```

will make the count unpredictable and require a traversal.

As said above, in JDK 9 or newer, you can simple use

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("a", "b", "c").peek(System.out::println).count());
```

and

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("a", "b", "c")
    .peek(System.out::println).filter(x -> true).count());
```

to see that the traversal does not happen when the count is predictable.